# Unable to locate element with python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

i want to click on button that means next and it wrote by 'بعدی'
in this page
https://www.tgju.org/profile/price_dollar_rl/history
here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
browser= webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path="geckodriver.exe")
browser.get('https://www.tgju.org/profile/price_dollar_rl/history');
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
wait = WebDriverWait(browser,20)
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="DataTables_Table_0_next"]')
```

and I get this error
Unable to locate element: //*[@id="DataTables_Table_0_next"]
but i copy exact id form inspect
 
thanks

Comment: What happens when you remove `options.add_argument("--headless")`?

Comment: @DebanjanB it does not work

Comment: So we need to solve the issue without `options.add_argument("--headless")` first then proceed to headless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a wait for element to be present. On this page it looks like it's dynamically loaded.

```
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "DataTables_Table_0_next"))
    )
```

Comment: raise error is 'TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)' @DMart

Comment: i scrape it by localhost in my system and it works thanks @DMart

Comment: Did my answer help? If so mark it as correct. It's a little unclear what your last message meant.